# Good request from browser but bad request from ruby?

Tags: ruby, request, google-api, http-status-code-400, typhoeus

I'm using the google custom search api and I'm trying to access it through some ruby code:

Here is a snippet of the code

```
req = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={my_key}&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=" + keyword, followlocation: true)
res = req.run
```

It appears that the body of the answer is this one:

```
    <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from main.rb:20:in `initialize'
    from main.rb:41:in `new'
    from main.rb:41:in `<main>'
```

When I try to do the same thing from the browser it works like a charm. Even more confusing is that this same code worked 12 hours ago. I only changed the keyword that it should look for, however it started returning the error.

Any suggestions? I'm sure that I have enough credits for more requests

Comment: Does your keyword contain any funky characters? Like `?#&/.+` etc. or any unicode characters?

Comment: I tried "sky line" and then "sky/ line" to escape the space. None seemed to return anything but the error

Comment: Try `sky+line` and `sky%20line` maybe. I think you should use `CGI::escape` to avoid any errors: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape

Comment: yep. Put it in an answer please so I can accept it

Comment: sky%20line won't work. The add sing I found to be  the most useful

Comment: Ok, glad to help. I summed my comment up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have problems with special characters in your get parameter `keyword`. If you enter the URL in your browser, the brower adjusts these. However, for ruby you need to escape these characters, in such a way that a string like `"sky line"` becomes `"sky+line"` and so on. There is a utility function [CGI::escape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape), which is used like this:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI::escape("sky line")
=> "sky+line"
```

Your fixed code would look something like this:

```
req = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={my_key}&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=" + CGI::escape(keyword), followlocation: true)
res = req.run
```

However, since you're using Typhoeus anyway, you should be able to use its `params` parameter and let Typhoeus handle the escaping:

```
req = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve",
   followlocation: true, 
   params: {q: keyword, key: my_key}
)
res = req.run
```

There's more examples on [Typhoeus' GitHub page](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus).

Comment: oh wow. Typhoeus is amazing. Thanks for letting me know those extra bits. I will make sure I read some more